# Ubuntu 12.04.1: Right mouse button doesnt work

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 on my new Lenovo IdeaPad Y580 M772DGE. Unfortunately the right mouse button is not working correctly. Every mouse button click is interpreted as a left mouse button click. I tried to uninstall and reinstall the synaptics (xserver-xorg-input-synaptics) drivers, but the problem is still present.

What else can I do? Any other suggestions?

Btw: My touchpad doesnt have a "Middle Mouse Button". Is it possible to emulate a "middle mouse click" with a keybord shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

If the right mouse button behaves like the left button and vice versa, try this:

What about the `mouse orientation` settings? Is it set to `Right handed`?